# "package A does not exist" while compiling from command prompt

Tags: java, import

```
package A;

 public class display

        {
             display()
               {
                  System.out.println("This is Package A");
               }
         }
```

save as display.java

```
package B;

import A.*;

 class Actor
          {

           public static void main(String args[])
             {
                     new display();
                    System.out.print("Package A class display imported in package B");
              }  
}
```

save as Actor.java

```
javac -d createpkg display.java(successful)

javac -d createpkg Actor.java(error)

Actor.java:2:package A does not exist
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question? and provide exact detail of problem you are facing?

Answer (score -1):

You import package A in package B by this type......

import A.display.

Package name with public class name .

Comment: It's fine if you do A.*